# Submit form automatically

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, submit

hey can anyone help me

I would like to automatically submit the form on page load is there anyway it could be done?

```
<form method='post' action='/delete-account.php'>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Confirm Account Removal" /></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method='post' name="myForm" id="myForm"  action='/delete-account.php'>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Confirm Account Removal" /></form>

 window.onload=function(){
          document.forms["myForm"].submit();
 }
```

Comment: i gave it a try and it didn't work

Comment: did you get any error??

Comment: Thanks! but i now got it working i added / edit document.getElementById("submit").click();

Comment: Have a great day

Answer (score 0):

You can submit this way by using the jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
       document.getElementById("myDataForm").submit();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method='post' id="myDataForm" name="myDataForm" action='/delete-account.php'>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Confirm Account Removal" /></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please try this.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work but thanks for the help / fast reply

Comment: Have a look at question tag, he is not mentioning jquery

Comment: @MikeJones please try now i have changed something on the answer. Definitely it will work

Comment: nope that also didn't work